# i want to scale object in geo node

Tags: geometry-nodes

How do I change origin of *Mesh > Primitive > Grid*,so that when I scale it normally, when origin is in center and we scale, it scale in all the direction from the center.

But when when the origin is in one of its edge, then we scale it, it scale in all the direction but keeps that edge at same position.

In the image you can see difference, one below cube has the center and the plane which is alone has edge as origin.

Grid has socket sizeX and sizeY, in the given image sizeY is increased but the postion of the edge is change

I don't know you understand my broken English but I want to change origin than scale, yah I know I can change position after scaling but to create procedural stuff and to make the node setup with few input in group input node its quite hard

[image: scaling the grid with different origin]

Comment: did u try scale elements? please share at least your whole node tree. You didn't even show us how you scaled. or maybe share your blend file so we can check it out on our own. thx

Comment: thx, your comment solved the issue

Comment: Hi @Chris,, I guess we should either make a brief  answer out of your comment, or mark the question to close without need for one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the scale elements node to scale your grid, so that the scaling of the grid acts as if the pivot point would be in the center.